# Circular loading before page loads Flutter

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-layout

I have a list of widgets and a function which returns a Container telling user to add to the list if the list of widgets is empty:

```
_isCountEmpty() {
      if (count == 0 || count == null) {
   //if no widgets in list
        return Container(
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Text('Press edit to start adding exercises',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40,
                  color: Colors.white,
                )));
      }
   //if widgets in list

      return ListView(
        children: children,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      );
    }
```

initState where count is obtained:

```
 void initState() {
getCount().then(updateCount);
super.initState(); }
```

The count value is received from another page using shared preferences which are called in my initState. Before the count value is received in the initState the screen thinks the value for count is null therefore for just a split second the Container() is returned just before the ListView.
Instead of this, I want the circular indicator to show while the screen is getting the value of count from initState, and then return the Container or ListView after the value for count is obtained

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code which would load your counter from shared preferences then you can replace the Text widget with whatever list you want or container if the `counter == 0 || counter == null`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int counter;
  Future<SharedPreferences> prefs;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
        future: prefs,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<SharedPreferences> snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          } else {
            counter = snapshot.data.getInt("counter");
            //Replace with whatever widget you want
            return Text("Loading is done your counter is : $counter");
          }
        },
      )),
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want this container to be a circular progress indicator because when the app first loads and there are no items in the widget list, I want it just to show the container and not with the loading screen.

Comment: Ah then i'm sorry I didn't properly understand your question could you please perhaps explain a bit more or post more code?

Comment: If your list is null, you can display circular indicator and display your container only if the list is empty. You can use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: I just updated the question, does this make more sense now?

Comment: @woprandi Thank you for your suggestion, however this would mean when the app is first built, it will return a circular loading screen instead of the container because count is defined as null.

Comment: @flutterNoob you have no choice to display a temporary widget since your value is got asynchronically

Comment: @flutterNoob I can help you setup a loading indicator while you are retrieving the value using a future builder but in that case it would display very briefly since it doesn't take a long time to load shared preferences

Comment: hi Abbas thank you for your answer it worked, however I dont understand why, does the future: prefs, find if there has been any information sent over ?

Comment: Hello! The idea is that some functions are "async" which means they return after a little while, so a future builder would allow u to have 2 "phases", phase one which is before the future resolves, phase 2 is after the future resolves. Please reference [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo) and [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for some more info